# How to read the JSON file in Angular 4 scripts

Tags: angular

I need to read the JSON file which we have stored locally in the project workspace, because I need to read the component.ts file.

Are there any basic steps?

Answer (score 0):

You can read JSON data using HTTP request

```
getJsonData(){
    let jsonUrl = 'Your json file path';
    return this.http.get(jsonUrl)
      .map( (response: Response) => {
        const data = response.json();
        return data; } );
}
```

Comment: If you're use http, you must "map" the respone and use response.json like @bipin patel shown If you use the new httpClient NOT use response.json. You have already the object directly

Comment: if it's work for you than tick right on my answer

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. You can do directly in a component or using a service. It's better create a service to separate the logic of the application. (If in a future you'll want change the way to access to the data you only must to change the service)

Your service

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { } //<-- inject HttpClient
    getData() {
        return this.http.get('../assets/data.json')
    }).catch(
        (error: Response) => {
        return Observable.throw(error);
    });
}
```

Your Component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private dataService:DataService){} //<--inject the service

  data:any //<--a variable
  ngOnInit(){
    this.dataService.getData().subscribe((data)=>
    {  
         this.data=data
    }
}
```

Remember, in your app.module declare the service

```
@NgModule({
   ...
   providers: [DataService,..]
}
```

Of course you can do all in the component, but it's disapproved